# How do I iterate between lists of different lenghts?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I have two lists which I need to Iterate together. Let me show how:

```
listA=[1,2,3,4]
listB=["A","B","C"]
```

From those lists I would like to have this list

```
ListC=("1A","2B","3C","4A")
```

And even make a longer list in which I can loop the same iteration

```
ListC=("1A","2B","3C","4A","1B","2C","3A","4C".... and so on)
```

I couldn`t find any tutorial online that would answer this question
Thanks.

Comment: How long do you want your `ListC` be? what is the end/last element criterion?

Answer (score 8):

Use `zip` and `itertools.cycle`:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> listA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> listB = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> [f'{x}{y}' for x, y in zip(listA, cycle(listB))]
['1A', '2B', '3C', '4A']

# listA:         1    2    3    4
# cycle(listB): "A"  "B"  "C"  "A"  "B"  "C" ...
```

`cycle` endlessly cycles through the elements of its argument; `zip` stops iterating after its shorter argument is exhausted.

You can use `cycle` with *both* lists, but the result will be an infinite sequence of values; you'll need to use something like `itertools.islice` to take a finite prefix of the result.

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> [f'{x}{y}' for x, y in islice(zip(cycle(listA), cycle(listB)), 8)]
['1A', '2B', '3C', '4A', '1B', '2C', '3A', '4B']

# cycle(listA):  1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   1  ...
# cycle(listB): "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "A" ...
# Note that the result itself is a cycle of 12 unique elements, because
# the least common multiple (LCM) of 3 and 4 is 12.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo to take care of this kind of problem. Here's code to repeat this 100 times:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

result = []
for i in range(100):
    result.append(str(l1[i % len(l1)]) + l2[i % len(l2)])

print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
listA=[1,2,3,4]
listB=["A","B","C"]
listC=[]

for a in listA:
    index = listA.index(a)
    if listA.index(a) > len(listB) - 1:
        if listC[-1][1] != listB[-1]:
            index = listB.index(listC[-1][1]) + 1
        else:
            index = 0
    listC.append(str(a)+listB[index])

print(listC)
```

Comment: Aside from being cumbersome, this assumes that the lists don't have any duplicates; `index` returns the index of the *first* occurrence of an item only.

Comment: thats not a good idea if elements of  `listA` aren't unique because `list.index`returns the first occurence of an element